# jQuery: Call 'complete' callback with .stop(xxx, false)

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-animate

There is a library X that animates the element `'.the-element'` and attaches a simple `complete`-callback for when the animation ends. That callback must be called, otherwise the library X will stop working.

The library X by itself does not support freezing (aka pausing all animations *where they are*) so I tried to do `jQuery('.the-element').stop(false, false);`. But now the callback is not called. Since jQuery does not support resuming a paused animation (would be preferred but I do not want to use a plugin for this), I want to call the `complete`-callback myself, so that the library X can then continue with what it does.

So the question comes up: How do I call the `complete`-callback while using `.stop(xxx, false)`?

Comment: If possible , can post `js` , `html` ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `options`-object of `$.fn.animate()` to place the callback at another event (in your case it would be `always`);

```
$(".the-element").animate(
    {property: 'value'}, {
        duration: 1000,
        done: function() {/* ... */}, // executes when animation reached end value
        complete: function() {/* ... */}, // executes when animation is complete
        fail:  function() {/* ... */}, // executes when animation don't go to end
        always: function() {/* ... */}, // executes always when animation is ended,
                                        // it may be completed or interrupted/stopped
    }
);
```

[Reference for $.fn.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Thanks for the nice suggestion, I am sure, this will help some people coming from google but this code is inside library X in my case, I have no power there.